# Can not start final quest for Minutemen - Fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4

Can not start final quest for Minutemen - Fallout 4

Spoiler

> The final quest "The Nuclear Option", for the Minutemen faction, won't start for me when playing Fallout 4. I have completed "Defend the Castle" and I have visited the institute and downloaded the data and given it to Sturges. I just said that he would get back to me and then nothing. Talking to Preston, in Sanctuary, gives me nothing but the repeating quests to help settlements. The only thing I can think of is that while in the Institute I talked to Father and decided to join them, thinking I would infiltrate them and get some good stuff, now the Institute missions have started but I want to get back to the minute men and do the Nuclear Option quest. If it's joining the institute that caused it, can I unjoin by making them mad somehow?

Comment: A) Have you been banished from the Institute yet? B) How many settlements do you have?

Comment: I have at least a dozen settlements. But yes, it turned out that I hadn't been was to chummy with the Institute to trigger this quest. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it now

Spoiler

> It was due to my good standing with the institute. To solve it I entered the Institute and started shooting, it seemed that killing an unnamed scientist turned the whole colony against me but not enough to trigger the "Banished from the Institute" quest line. I needed to return to the institute and kill yet another person, this time a name Scientist which triggered "Banished from the Institute". 
> After escaping I traveled to Sanctuary where I meet up with someone who told me to go to the Castle and the quest "Defend the Castle" started. After finishing that one the last quest "Nuclear Option" started.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

The game provides you some explicit message when you are about to do some "no U-turn choices", like declaring a total war against a faction. So feel free to try things ;)

In order to start "Nuclear Option" you have to be banished from Institute, and (complete "Form Ranks") OR (already have 8 settlements at least).
Here are some relevant links :

- quest from wiki (spoilers): http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Nuclear_Option_%28Minutemen%29
- faction quests list by faction: https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/41arz4/how_far_you_can_go_until_factions_turn_against/
- an awesome chart with each relation between faction quests:
  http://cdn.gamerant.com/wp-content/uploads/fallout-4-mission-tree.png